# Collect two values including a foreach loop and enter to the database, how does it works?

Tags: php, web

Actually I have created a fitnesstool that allows you to safe your daily workout to a database. There is one page where the workout will be shown, and in another page,shows where you can enter the values of the daily workout.

Two values must be collected:

- the fitnessplan, who is safed at the database **fitnessplans**
- the values where entered by the form (collected with foreach)

While collecting the stations of the fitnessplan I get a problem. Only one station of the fitnessplan is collected, but the values of the form were completed and correctly collected.

It seems as if the while-loop starts only once, then the foreach-loop is starting, but the while-loop isn't starting again.

```
$sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM fitnessplans WHERE uid='$sess_id'");
   if($sql->num_rows != 0) {
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
           $content = $row['content'];

           foreach ($mass as $elem1) {
           if(!empty($elem1)) {
               $sql = $db->query("INSERT INTO sessions (uid,content,value,datetime) VALUES ('$sess_id','$content','$elem1',$time)");
          } 
           header("Location: index.php#trainings");
       }
    }   
}
```

Comment: You are navigating away in the while loop.. so it will only loop once.. move the `header`code line

Comment: Well issuing a Location header inside a loop that is supposed to run more than once does make little sense to begin with. Are you even selecting multiple rows there? You have not told us anything relevant about your data structure in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems as if the while-loop starts only once, then the foreach-loop
>   is starting but the while-loop isn't starting again.

You are indeed correct :

```
header("Location: index.php#trainings");
```

That line operates a redirection. In other words, once your loop has iterated once, your PHP code moves the user to another page. There is thus effectively no way to have the code in that loop executed more than once as it is.

EDIT : Since it doesn't seem to be the redirection that messes with your execution, it's certainly something else. However, I strongly advise you to take a fresh look at your code and what you intend it to do, since I doubt that you actually want to have a redirection each time the while loops.
However, not knowing what's inside `$mass` when the foreach is called, I'm incline to say that maybe it's what causes you issues.

Can you provide a dump of that array ?

Comment: Not really ... a header call does not end a loop; or anything else for that matter. (That is why it is important to `exit` scripts after such a location header, if one does not want following code to be executed still.)

Comment: Thank you for your support.
Unfortunately, the problem is still there.

Comment: I know that, but the redirection won't work as the OP presumably intends it to do. However, won't the redirection mess with the rest of the code, turning it into a waste of resource ?

Comment: here's the whole code: pastebin.com/KH6JcvvN thanks your help :)

Comment: Please, edit your question instead of posting links in comment. Insert the code and outputs directly into your answer if that's of a reasonable size, so that it's easier for everyone willing to help to access the relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM fitnessplans WHERE uid='$sess_id'");
   if($sql->num_rows != 0) {
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
           $content = $row['content'];

           foreach ($mass as $elem1) {
           if(!empty($elem1)) {
               $sql = $db->query("INSERT INTO sessions (uid,content,value,datetime) VALUES ('$sess_id','$content','$elem1',$time)");
          } 

       }
    } 

     header("Location: index.php#trainings");  
}
```